# ValueError: Can not squeeze dim[1], expected a dimension of 1,

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

**ValueError: Can not squeeze dim[1], expected a dimension of 1, got 3 for 'metrics/sparse_categorical_accuracy/Squeeze' (op: 'Squeeze') with input shapes: [?,3].**

The Iris dataset
In this assignment, you will use the Iris dataset. It consists of 50 samples from each of three species of Iris (Iris setosa, Iris virginica and Iris versicolor). Four features were measured from each sample: the length and the width of the sepals and petals, in centimeters. For a reference, see the following papers:

R. A. Fisher. "The use of multiple measurements in taxonomic problems". Annals of Eugenics. 7 (2): 179–188, 1936.
Your goal is to construct a neural network that classifies each sample into the correct class, as well as applying validation and regularisation techniques.

Load and preprocess the data
First read in the Iris dataset using datasets.load_iris(), and split the dataset into training and test sets.

You can now construct a model to fit to the data. Using the Sequential API, build your model according to the following specifications:

The model should use the input_shape in the function argument to set the input size in the first layer.
The first layer should be a dense layer with 64 units.
The weights of the first layer should be initialised with the He uniform initializer.
The biases of the first layer should be all initially equal to one.
There should then be a further four dense layers, each with 128 units.
This should be followed with four dense layers, each with 64 units.
All of these Dense layers should use the ReLU activation function.
The output Dense layer should have 3 units and the softmax activation function.
In total, the network should have 10 layers.

```
from numpy.random import seed
seed(8)
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn import datasets, model_selection 
get_ipython().run_line_magic('matplotlib', 'inline')

from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Flatten, Softmax

def read_in_and_split_data(iris_data):
 
    return model_selection.train_test_split(
         iris_data["data"], 
         iris_data["target"], 
         test_size=0.1
    )

# In[3]:

# Run your function to generate the test and training data.

iris_data = datasets.load_iris()
(train_data, test_data, 
 train_targets, test_targets) = read_in_and_split_data(iris_data)

# We will now convert the training and test targets using a one hot encoder.

# In[4]:

# Convert targets to a one-hot encoding

train_targets = tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(np.array(train_targets))
test_targets = tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(np.array(test_targets))

#### GRADED CELL ####

# Complete the following function. 
# Make sure to not change the function name or arguments.

def get_model(input_shape):
    """
    This function should build a Sequential model according to 
    the above specification. Ensure the weights are initialised 
    by providing the input_shape argument in the first layer, given by the
    function argument.
    Your function should return the model.
    """
    model = Sequential([
       Dense(64, activation = "rely", 
             kernel_initializer='he_uniform', 
             bias_initializer='ones', 
             input_shape=input_shape),
       Dense(128, activation = "relu"),
       Dense(128, activation = "relu"),
       Dense(128, activation = "relu"),
       Dense(128, activation = "relu"),
       Dense(64, activation = "relu"),
       Dense(64, activation = "relu"),
       Dense(64, activation = "relu"),
       Dense(64, activation = "relu"),
       Dense(3, activation = "softmax"),
       ])
    return model    
    
# In[16]:

# Run your function to get the model

model = get_model(train_data[0].shape)


# #### Compile the model
# 
# You should now compile the model using the `compile` method. 
# Remember that you need to specify an optimizer, a loss function and 
# a metric to judge the performance of your model.

# In[23]:

#### GRADED CELL ####

# Complete the following function. 
# Make sure to not change the function name or arguments.

def compile_model(model):
 
    #model.compile(loss="sparse_categorical_crossentropy", optimizer="adam")
    opt = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.0001) 
    acc = tf.keras.metrics.SparseCategoricalAccuracy() 
    model.compile(optimizer=opt, 
                  loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', 
                  metrics=[acc] ) 

# In[24]:

# Run your function to compile the model

compile_model(model)

#### GRADED CELL ####

# Complete the following function. 
# Make sure to not change the function name or arguments.

def train_model(model, train_data, train_targets, epochs):
    """
    This function should train the model for the given number of epochs on the 
    train_data and train_targets. 
    Your function should return the training history, as returned by model.fit.
    """
    return model.fit(train_data, train_targets, epochs)

# Run the following cell to run the training for 800 epochs.

# In[26]:

# Run your function to train the model

history = train_model(model, train_data, train_targets, epochs=800)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because you have the wrong loss function. Your targets are one-hot encoded, so you should **not** use `'sparse_categorical_crossentropy'`. Instead, you should use `'categorical_crossentropy'`

Same thing for `acc = tf.keras.metrics.SparseCategoricalAccuracy()`. It should be `acc = tf.keras.metrics.CategoricalAccuracy()`

Comment: Thanks! But now I got:
InvalidArgumentError:  logits and labels must have the same first dimension, got logits shape [135,3] and labels shape [405]
  [[node loss/output_1_loss/SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits/SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits (defined at /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/ops.py:1751) ]] [Op:__inference_distributed_function_1479]

Function call stack:
distributed_function

Comment: Maybe restart your kernel? I copy pasted your code with _both_ of my edits and it works

Comment: nope :( same error yet. tried a notebook from the scratch, but still the same

Comment: print(tf.__version__) 2.2.0